# Getting Uncaught ReferenceError Error On Responsive DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I was using Resposive DataTables perfectly but is just starts putting out an error of:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

which I click on `+` sign!

I google this but wasn't able to find any thing for that! Can you please let me know what might cause this issue!
[image]

> Update

```
var allDataTbl = $('#all-data-tbl').DataTable( {
        bFilter: false,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
       buttons: [  
    'copy', 
    {
       extend: 'excel', 
       title: 'BC Run of River Decision Support Tool'
    },
    {
       extend: 'csv', 
       title: 'BC Run of River Decision Support Tool'
    }
]
    } );

 request.done(function(mapInfo) {
                    var arr = [];
                    $.each(mapInfo, function(i,v) {
                            arr.push($.map(v, function(v1) {
                            return v1;
                        }));
                    });
                    allDataTbl.clear().rows.add(arr).draw();


 )};
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Sure, please take a look at the Update

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide the source code for what happens when clicking on that "+", it would be helpful.

It looks like your error variable "e" cannot be accessed in its scope or its not declared anywhere. If it is defined, it can only be accessed in its own scope. If you want a variable to be accessible globally, you can remove the "var" keyword although that is not recommended.

Go to your "dataTables.responsive.js" file and search for all the instances of "e".